# HTML - Rename index.html for every folder

Tags: html, .htaccess, data-structures

So I am fairly new to html and web development. I am currently playing around with a small website and wondered if it is possible to rename the 'index.html' file in every subfolder.

I have read a little about the `htaccess` file but could not find anything specific to my problem.

I want to be able to have something like `www.example.com/test` with `test.html` in the `/test` folder acting as the `index.html` and the same for `www.example.com/apple` with `apple.html` and so on, without having to have 100 index files in total as that seems pretty confusing.

Is this possible with `htaccess`and how if it is? If not is it possible at all?

Comment: why do you want to do this?? for URI SEO purpose??

Comment: you could do this by creating a PHP router, this also includes editing the `htaccess` file and, if well made, is very easy to use, there are a ton of routers already available online, you could take a look at those and make your own, or use one of them if you can get the premissions

Comment: I basically only want to do this so that the structure of the website is cleaner for me. I dont really care about user experience or SEO. I just want to organize my site. Another exmple:

`www.fruits.com/appel` should contain everything connected to apples. And the start page of that subdirectory would normally be called `index.html`. But after a while that would add up to a lot of `index.html` documents for `fruits.com/banana` `fruits.com/pineapple` etc. I just want to be able to call the `index.html` file in `/apple` 'apple.html' so that i know what index file it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove html (to avoid duplicate content)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite html only if file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess you do like this

```
RewriteRule ^index.*$ index.php [NC]
```

So in other words you replace index.php with what you want to be changed and index with the name that users you want to see.You can also do this with arguments like

```
RewriteRule ^welcome.*$ index.php?page=welcome [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule i am assuming files and folder's are present in manner as you have said.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1/$1.html [L]
```